# Twig For numeric

Tags: variables, for-loop, numbers, twig

I would like to know how how to make a like java in twig

java

```
i=10;
for(int x=0;x<i;x++){}
```

I found this on twig:

```
{% for i in 0..10 %}
* {{ i }} {% endfor %}
```

But i don't know how to change that 10 to a int variable in twig.

Answer (score 1):

Just place the variable in your `for`?

```
{% set i = 10 %}
{% for j in 1..i %}
    {{ j }}
{% endfor %}
```